# Pull Request "reviewers" using github "history"

Tags: github, github-enterprise

Is there any way (for on premise github) to :

For N number of files in the Pull Request.

Look at the history of those files.

And add any/all github users (on the history) .. to the code reviewers list of users?

I have searched around.

I found "in general" items like this:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-automate-code-reviews-on-github-41be46250712/

But cannot find anything in regards to the specific "workflow" I describe above.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the list of changed files to the text file from PR. Then we can run the git command below to get the list of users included in last version's blame. For each file we get from file list, run the blame command. This might be also simple script.

- Generate txt file from list of files of PR.
- Traverse all filenames through txt file. (python, bash etc.)
- Run blame command and store in a list.
- Add reviewers to the PR from that list manually or some JS script for it.

For github spesific: [list-pull-requests-files](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests-files)
The blame command is something like :

```
git blame filename --porcelain | grep  "^author " | sort -u
```

As a note, if there are users who are not available in github anymore. Extra step can be added after we get usernames to check whether they exist or not. (It looks achievable through github API)